# How can I render a grails model to javascript using a post method from a controller action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

At a jquery event I want to call upon a controller action and use its data. The way I did it until now was:

```
$('#my-button').click(function(){
$.post("${createLink(controller: 'myview', action: 'myAction')}", {param1: x, param2: y},
function(data){
    //in here I want to use both elements of the model as I see fit.
})

});
```

My controller method looks like this:

```
def myAction(param1, param2){
//some data manipulation goes here

render model: [returnValue1: variable1, returnValue2: variable2];
}
```

My question is how can I access variable1 and variable2 from my $.post method? If I don't use a model and just return one of those variables, data will equal exactly that variable, but in this case it won't.

Can anybody tell me how to access those variables in that model please? Just calling ${returnValue1} does not work in that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can render a json object representing your model. Here's the [render documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/render.html)

```
render(contentType: "text/json") {
    [returnValue1: variable1, returnValue2: variable2]
}
```

or

```
render([returnValue1: variable1, returnValue2: variable2] as JSON)
```